# Max length Rule doesn't work for {exp:channel:form}

Tags: channel-form

I have this form tag

```
{exp:channel:form
    channel="xxxxx"
    class="form-horizontal row-fluid"
    date_picker="no"
    error_handling="inline"
    include_assets="no"
    include_jquery="no"
    return="/foo/bar/"
    rules:title="required|max_length[5]"
}
```

I am trying to limit title to 5 characters. However, it does not seem to work since I was able to post titles with more than 5 characters without the form complaining.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation ([user guide, channel form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/index.html#rules-my-field-name)) does seem to mention (custom) fields. (a quick look at the source of channel:form lib indicates the same).

You could validate length with the help of a little bit of javascript, and/or report a bug (feature request) at EllisLab that rules should also apply to default fields.

Comment: +1 for reporting this as bug. https://support.ellislab.com/bugs

Comment: I reported the bug. Waiting for reply.

Comment: looks like "accepted" https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20006